# How to create IAM policy in AWS in order to deny creation of EC2 based on tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have the following policy, however using these policy users can still create resrouces with this tag, however they just will have all access denied to the resource with this policy. Is there a way to deny EC2 creation based on a tag?

```
{
    "'Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
           {
                    "Sid": "VisualEditor@"
                    "Effect": "Deny"
                     "Action": [
                            "ec2:*"
                     ],
                    "Resource": [
                             "arn:aws: ec2:*:*: instance/*"
                    ],
                    "Condition": {
                             "StringEquals": {
                                 "aws: ResourceTag/Environment": "test"
                              }
                     }
           }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyEC2CreationWithTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Environment": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **RequestTag** condition key:

The following IAM policy denies users to create a specific tag "Environment" with values "test" when launching new EC2 instances:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToEC2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "RunInstancesWithTagRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Environment": "test"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**RequestTag condition key**

> The aws:RequestTag/tag-key condition key used to compare the key-value
> pair passed in the user request with the tag pair specified in the IAM
> policy. The condition key is available for actions that create a
> resource or tag on a resource, and checks the value of the tag.

**ResourceTag condition key**

> The aws:ResourceTag/tag-key condition key compares the tag key-value
> pair specified in the IAM policy with the key-value pair that's
> attached to the AWS resource. For more information, see Controlling
> access to AWS resources.

Hope it helps.

Useful Resources:

- [Controlling access to AWS resources using tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html)
- [IAM tag-based restriction policies](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-tag-based-restriction-policies)
- [IAM policy permission ec2 tags](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/iam-policy-permission-ec2-tags-vpc)